# How to sort values in arrays, aggregate it, efficiently way to count the similar records in SQL

Tags: sql, count, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, aggregate-functions

I need to count and aggregate by types properties from the table.

These are some examples of **"Title"** column:

| Row | Title |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | WATLINGTON STATION - 9 HOUSES AND INDUSTRIAL UNITS |
| 2 | STATION ROAD YATE - 1 BUNGALOW & 2 HOUSES |
| 3 | THE OLD VICARAGE CARR LANE - HOUSE & STABLE BLOCK |

So, then to clean these rows I've used **REPLACE()** AND **REGEX()** functions:

```
SELECT SPLIT(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(REPLACE(TRIM(REGEXP_REPLACE(REGEXP_SUBSTR(REPLACE("Title",'-2',''), '[^-]*$'), '[0-9]+')),'/', '&'), ' &  ','&'),' AND ','&'),' & ','&'),'& ','&'),'.',''),'&') AS "Category",
COUNT("Category") AS "Frequency"
FROM DATA.PROPERTIES
GROUP BY "Category" 
ORDER BY "Frequency" DESC;
```

And I got rows like:

| Category | Frequency |
| --- | --- |
| "HOUSES" | 12432 |
| "FLATS" | 76736 |
| "HOUSE" | 23865 |
| "APARTMENTS" | 18814 |
| "HOUSES", "FLATS" | 3245 |
| "FLATS", "HOUSES" | 1342 |
| "FLATS", "RETAIL UNIT" | 362 |
| "FLATS", "HOUSE" | 461 |
| "FLATS", "RETAIL" | 890 |
| "FLATS", "RETAIL UNITS" | 287 |

I've gave some results. As you can see **[ "HOUSES", "FLATS" ]** and **[ "FLATS", "HOUSES" ]**
should be joined into one, cause it similar and it should be like **[ "HOUSES", "FLATS" ]** and 4587.

So, I assume that somehow I should re-order every array in ASC or DESC order and aggregate it.
And similar question about three rows like **[ "FLATS", "RETAIL UNIT" ]**, **[ "FLATS", "RETAIL" ]**, **[ "FLATS", "RETAIL UNITS" ]**.

Do you have any ideas how to resolve it??

May be the way using ARRAY_AGG or something else. I have no any ideas now, but would like to resolve this question.

Comment: Are you only looking for aggregation from the output you have mentioned in the question i.e. to aggregate similar category items and further add their frequencies for the final result?

Comment: @Pankaj yes, you are right.

Comment: How about categories like HOUSE and HOUSES, are they to be considered same or different?

Comment: "I assume that somehow I should re-order every array in ASC or DESC order and aggregate it." - Yes, that is the option I can think of too, along with stripping extra words or characters such as 'S' at the end or words like 'Units', so that arrays can be compared or aggregated.

Comment: @Pankaj HOUSE and HOUSES are they should be different. But I don't know how to do this operation. Do you have an opinion or solution to realize it?

Comment: There does not seem to be a common element here. If HOUSE and HOUSES are different, then how come  [ "FLATS", "RETAIL UNIT" ], [ "FLATS", "RETAIL UNITS" ] are same, as here too the only difference is UNIT and UNITS. We can make the logic by only stripping or replacing UNITS/UNIT with blank and then aggregating. But I am not sure what other kind of word-pairs may by there in your data that are similar or need cleaning. I can post the basic logic, if that is what you are looking for to reorder and aggregate.

Comment: Thanks, @Pankaj. But how to reorder values in the arrays? what is the function or steps need using to do that?

Comment: I have posted an example, which may not be the exact thing you need, but it shows as you asked the reorder and aggregate part. For string elimination, you might need to work more on that, as I am not fully aware of the data and what kind of cleaning it might need.

Answer (score 1):

Example showing reorder and aggregate  -
Idea is to first flatten the array and then reorder them while aggregating. Finally once they are in order simple grouping can be used, which will group all arrays that were previously like ['a','b'], ['b','a'] under one group.

```
with cte (category, frequency) as (
    select array_construct('HOUSES'),12432 union all
    select array_construct('FLATS'),76736 union all
    select array_construct('HOUSE'),23865 union all
    select array_construct('APARTMENTS'),18814 union all
    select array_construct('HOUSES', 'FLATS'),3245 union all
    select array_construct('FLATS', 'HOUSES'),1342 union all
    select array_construct('FLATS', 'RETAIL UNIT'),362 union all
    select array_construct('FLATS', 'HOUSE'),461 union all
    select array_construct('FLATS', 'RETAIL'),890 union all
    select array_construct('FLATS', 'RETAIL UNITS'),287
), cte_1 as
    (select seq,value,c1.frequency
        from cte c1,
        lateral flatten(input=>category)
        order by seq, value
    ), cte_2 as
        (select array_agg(value) category, frequency
            from cte_1
            group by seq,frequency)
    select category, sum(frequency)
        from cte_2
        group by category;
```

| CATEGORY | SUM(FREQUENCY) |
| --- | --- |
| [ "FLATS", "HOUSE" ] | 461 |
| [ "FLATS", "RETAIL" ] | 890 |
| [ "HOUSE" ] | 23865 |
| [ "FLATS" ] | 76736 |
| [ "FLATS", "RETAIL UNITS" ] | 287 |
| [ "APARTMENTS" ] | 18814 |
| [ "FLATS", "RETAIL UNIT" ] | 362 |
| [ "HOUSES" ] | 12432 |
| [ "FLATS", "HOUSES" ] | 4587 |

Answer (score 1):

I really like Panka's answer, but the ORDER BY should not be in the step of CTE and should be inside the ARRRAY_AGG because a) there is a command to solve this b) the order of CTE is unimportant, and relying on order of rows is a magic that will burn you.

Also the CTE2 and CTE can be merged into one step, if you alias the FLATEN you can see what is happening:

```
with fake_data_table (category, frequency) as (
    select split(column1, '|'), column2 
    from values 
        ('HOUSES', 12432),
        ('FLATS', 76736),
        ('HOUSE', 23865),
        ('APARTMENTS', 18814),
        ('HOUSES|FLATS', 3245),
        ('FLATS|HOUSES', 1342),
        ('FLATS|RETAIL UNIT', 362),
        ('FLATS|HOUSE', 461),
        ('FLATS|RETAIL', 890),
        ('FLATS|RETAIL UNITS', 287)
), part_a as (
    select array_agg(f.value) within group (order by f.seq, f.value) as category, 
        d.frequency
    from fake_data_table as d,
    lateral flatten(input=>category) f
    group by f.seq, d.frequency
)
select category, sum(frequency)
from part_a
group by category 
order by 1;
```

gives:

| CATEGORY | SUM(FREQUENCY) |
| --- | --- |
| [ "APARTMENTS" ] | 18,814 |
| [ "FLATS" ] | 76,736 |
| [ "FLATS", "HOUSE" ] | 461 |
| [ "FLATS", "HOUSES" ] | 4,587 |
| [ "FLATS", "RETAIL" ] | 890 |
| [ "FLATS", "RETAIL UNIT" ] | 362 |
| [ "FLATS", "RETAIL UNITS" ] | 287 |
| [ "HOUSE" ] | 23,865 |
| [ "HOUSES" ] | 12,432 |